# What is the purpose of 'Number()' in indexedDB get() method

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

According to the documentation linked below, `get()` has a single parameter: `key`. In the description is:

> Key identifying the record to be retrieved. This can also be an
>   IDBKeyRange in which case the function retreives the first existing
>   value in that range.

In the example code below, using `get(Number("1"))`, will find the record. Using only `get("1")`, result is empty. (The primary/only key is 'num' and is auto-increment.)

```
function removeRecord(num) {
    var transaction = db.transaction(['queueStore'], 'readwrite');
    var store = transaction.objectStore('queueStore');

    // Check if the record exists & to identify the record
    store.get(Number(num)).onsuccess = function(event) {
        /*      ^ here     this works  */
        var result = event.target.result;
        if(result) {
            number = result.number;
        }
    };
}
```

I have not been able to find the answer in the [Indexed Database API](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBObjectStore-get-IDBRequest-any-key) or by search.

What does Number accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Number constructor when called as a function (that is, without `new`) converts the parameter to a number and returns that value. So, `Number("1")` returns the number `1`.

There's no point to coding `Number("1")` explicitly; you'd simply use `1`. It's useful if you know you might get a string value. In your case, the API is performing an exact comparison against your key, and if the real key is a number then it will never `===` any string.

The unary `+` operator does essentially the same thing, so `+"1"` is also `1`. Some people prefer to call `Number()` explicitly because it's a little more explicit.

The `parseFloat()` function *also* will convert a string to a number, but unlike the `Number()` constructor or unary `+`, `parseFloat()` will allow for non-numeric content at the end of the input string:

```
console.log(parseFloat("123hello world")); // 123
console.log(+"123hello world"); // NaN
```

Comment: I must be getting confused looking at the debugger output. So, `store.get(1)` is the simplest usage ?

Comment: @David well `store.get(1)` is the simplest thing to do if you want the record with key `1`, yes.